# Parallel Evaluation of Multiple Functions and Return the First to Finish

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, parallelization

I have two functions which calculate the same thing using different methods. Sometimes, the first method is much faster than the second method. Other times, the other way around. Just pretend this depends on a random coin-flip.

Can I evaluate both functions in parallel, and stop both evaluations as soon as one has finished?

*Pseudo-code*:

```
myMethod1[a_,b_]:=With[{p=Pause[RandomInteger[10]]},a+b]
myMethod2[a_,b_]:=With[{p=Pause[RandomInteger[10]]},a+b]
ParallelReturnFastest[{myMethod1[4,5],myMethod2[4,5]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `ParallelTry`? You could use it here as follows

```
myMethod1[a_, b_] := With[{p = Pause[RandomInteger[10]]}, Print["myMethod1"]; a + b]
myMethod2[a_, b_] := With[{p = Pause[RandomInteger[10]]}, Print["myMethod2"]; a + b]

ParallelTry[#[4, 5] &, {myMethod1, myMethod2}]
```

Comment: The description of `ParallelTry` is literally "evaluates $f_i$ in parallel, returning the first result received". So yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
ParallelSubmit[
 {
  a = AbsoluteTiming@Table[i, {i, 10000}][[1]]; Print[a];Abort[],
  a = AbsoluteTiming@Table[i, {i, 20000}][[1]]; Print[a];Abort[]
  }]
```

This will send the tasks to sub-kernels. Following evaluation of the

```
WaitAll[%]
```

will run your tasks and the output will be like:

> {0.000252534, 1}, $Aborted

That is first kernel have stopped all the evaluation loop.